# How can I implement helper vars (Template tags) outside of meteor templates, i.e. within a head tag?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Currently I can setup a static head.html that meteor will use, however it must not reside in a template tag and because of that I have no way of providing context to it.

So let's say I have head.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Static Title</title>
</head>
```

What I would like to do is:

```
<head>
  <title>{{dynamicTitle}}</title>
</head>
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Meteor does not provide a way to change the content in the `<head>` element dynamically, but you can do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helpers option are only available for template instances.

> Each template has a local dictionary of helpers that are made
>   available to it, and this call specifies helpers to add to the
>   template's dictionary.

from [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)

You should use here [registerHelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) for this (elaborating example)

Iron router `onBeforeAction` can be an option here.

```
Router.map(function() {
      return this.route('exampleRoute', {
        path: '/',
        onBeforeAction: function() {
          return document.title = "Example Dynamic title";
        }
      });
    });
```

For more look this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/292)

This can be easy done with Javascript and [Tracker](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun)

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  document.title = Session.get("myTitle");
})
```

Open the console and type this.

```
Session.set("myTitle","Test new title");
```

Check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/266) also

Comment: Thank you Ethaan, very well answered :)